# RabbitMQ and NiFi

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-nifi

I am new to NiFi, and advice welcomed.

We get data sent in from external sources in many small records. I am thinking of pulling those records into NiFi via RabbitMQ. I'd like to "spool" or "batch" those records up into larger grouping (perhaps based on some index in the records), and when a group of records reaches a certain size threshold write out to S3.

How to best accomplish this in NiFi? Any other suggestions?

Thanks, Gary

Answer (score 5):

RabbitMQ is based upon [AMQP](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html). Nifi supports a processor for AMQP called as [ConsumeAMQP](https://nifi.apache.org/docs.html). You will find Additional details in link which has documentation specific to RabbitMQ. Configure the processor according to the documentation and you are good to go.

For the second part you need to use PutS3Object processor and there you will be able define the thresholds.

Answer (score -1):

This should be achievable... I don't know that much about RabbitMQ, but assuming that it supports a JMS interface, then you could probably use NiFi's ConsumeJMS processor, followed by MergeContent to merge until your threshold is reached, and then PutS3Object to write to S3.